# openFileOutput does not create the file

Tags: android

I used the following code to create a file:

```
        FileOutputStream fos = app.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
        fos.write(content.getBytes());
        fos.close();
```

the file is create on the emulator but it is not created on my device (Samsung Galaxy Tab sdk 2.3).

There are no exception and no logs.

If I use getFilesDir I get a path that doe not exists. /data/data/it.xyz.xyz/files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should definitely work. How are you checking if the file actually exists? What I mean is: without root access when you use e.g. a File Manager you won't be able to access the /data/.. folders, but you can access that file from your own application.